# How to establish a powershell session from a local machine to a Virtual Machine

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine

I want to connect to a Virtual Machine (Microsoft windows NT) which is MFA enabled, from my Local machine which are in different domains and run the PowerShell scripts on VM.
Also I log on to my VM using a different User and password.

At First, I tried to establish session between cross VM's which belong to the same domain which was successful using the below script and was able to do so

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "VmName"
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {Get-ScheduledTask | Format-Table}
```

Then, I tried to establish a PowerShell Remote session between my local machine to the VM but it fails, using the same command and I also tried to use the credentials property but it still fails

I am not sure of what steps are to be followed to connect from my local to a VM in different domain.

Can somebody help me ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `New-PSSession -VMName "VmName"` <-- different parameter set (notice `-VMName` instead of `-ComputerName`)

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were connecting to a _local_ VM on your machine